# Package incompatibility between 32bit C++ and 64bit python

Tags: debian, python, c++

I am working on a project where I need to compile a C++ wrapper on a ARM processor while also working on a python project which uses the C++ wrapper. It's on a Rock Pi E with 64 bit Debian 10.

For the C++ wrapper, since one of the library which I have to use is only in 32bit for ARM architectures and I can't recompile it, I have to use `g++:armhf` to compile my project since I can't have a project mixing 32bit and 64bit.

On the other side, I use this wrapper in python. Which I also installed in 32bit with `python:armhf`. And I can use it without problems with `ctypes` and `CDLL`.

My current problem occurs when I tried to install python modules. Since I have to use pip but when I tried to install it with `apt`, it only finds it in 64bit which overrided g++ and python to arm64. When I try to force pip to ARM32 with `python3-pip:armhf`, it only says that it is referenced somewhere but I can't find where.

I saw that [MSL - loadlib](https://msl-loadlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) could give me the possibiliy to use my [compiled 32bit library in my 64bit python script](https://msl-loadlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interprocess_communication.html), but it requires some packages which are not found by apt such as `libgfortran3` for example.

From what I can understand, the best way to make it work. Would be to have a way to install `pip3` in 32bit and hoping that the modules that I use are also compatible 32bit.

The other way I see, would be to make MSL-loadlib work. But I would need a way to have `g++:armhf` to compile the c++ and `g++:arm64` for python installed at the same time, which doesn't seem possible.

Is there something I am missing which could make it possible ?

From what I understood and some of the comment told me, I may have to ask and wait for a updated version of the 32bit library which blocks me.

Comment: Are you saying it removed `g++:armhf` in order to install x64 g++ library?  If you are trying to target ARM64 that does not make sense  You should be trying to install `g++:arm64` you can't use x86 libraries to satisfy library requirements to build an ARM64 project.

Comment: Yes, when I install `python3-pip` it replaces `g++:armhf` with `g++:arm64`. I have to use a library which came already precompiled in 32bit so I can't just compile the rest of my project in 64bit.

Comment: It's been years since I attempt to compile a multiple library project.  When I looked into the process to compile OpenWRT a few years ago, I determined that I would have to compile each project for the same architecture, otherwise I would be unable to compile the project as a whole.  Why are you targeting ARM64 if you have a single ARM32 library anyways?  Anyways you might want to edit your question to be explicitly about which library, " g++ in 64bit", is confusing to even a knowledgeable reader like myself.

Comment: To the point (and @Ramhounds point), this simply can't work.  You are either 64bit or 32bit .  32 bit procs can't access 64 bit libs (or visa versa).  You either need to do the whole thing 32bit OR get a 64bit version of the library you are referencing.  Do you not have access to the source of that lib to rebuild it?  That sounds very un-linux like.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas No, I don't have acces to the source code. It's not a free library :/ 
@Ramhound I am not trying to build it to ARM64 since as you both said it's not really possible. This is why I wanted to install python  in 32 bit so I could use my C++ lib with CDLL which work fines. But I can't install the wanted modules for python since when I install pip, it overrides g++ (and others) from `armhf` to `arm64`.
I'm goint to try to clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

pip itself is purely python (so is setuptools), so there's no such thing as 32-bit or 64-bit for it. I'm not sure how exactly you installed 32-bit python (or how debian handles the multi-arch stuff -- assuming that upstream even does that for python), but if you in any case could not find the python package (and its dependencies) that are packaged in deb and in the way/paths that it suits your 32-bit python installation, you can consider using [ensurepip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html).

In fact, if you make use [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), pip will ready for you to use in the virtual environment upon its creation.